# Broken Ubuntu installation while restarting

Tags: data-recovery

I think that my Ubuntu installation lost power during an update, and now when I poweron it freezes at either a blank screen or the splash screen. I booted to recovery mode and used the repair packages option and did `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && dpkg --configure -a` without fixing the problem.

Any other suggestions or would I be best off just backing up my home directory and reinstalling?

Answer (score 1):

Boot into recovery mode, and enter the following:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and `sudo apt-get -f install`

followed by

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dis-upgrade
```

Should work now...